# Need to create plugin between osgi bundles

Tags: plugins, osgi

I had created few bundles in my application.
I want to plug those bundles like this:
[image]

Simply I want to plug in and plug out these bundles as I want for a specific fl/reason.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: As shown in the image, I created such bundles and want to plug those in a way they pass data for specific business logic.

Comment: Then you should write classes and functions.

Comment: Or OSGi services for all the inter-bundle connections.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on again?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a plugin model and chose OSGi without reading up on how to do this?

If you want to create a plugin model in OSGi then you use *services*. Services define a contract *between* bundles. So in this case your Core Bundle has a number of places where you business logic could 'plug-in'. For each of these places you you need to define the *service contract*. A service contract is defined by a Java package, it usually requires one or more interfaces.

Now in your Core Bundle you will have *components*. These components do the actual work in OSGi. To use the plugins in a component the component depends on the plugin services.

So lets say you have a component that needs to know the price of a product but that price can come from eBay, Amazon, or Ali Baba. So we first design the service contract:

```
public interface SupplierPlugin {
    Set<Product> findProducts( String query ) throws Exception;
    boolean buy( String id, String count) throws Exception;
    String getSupplierId() throws Exception;
}

public class Product extends DTO {
    public String     supplier;
    public String     id;
    public String     name;
    public String     description;
    public Price      price;
    public int        inStock;
    public Duration   deliveryTime;
}
```

So how does this look in your *component*?

```
@Component
public class OrderProduct implements REST {

     @Reference
     volatile List<SupplierPlugin> suppliers;

     public Product findProducts(String query) {
         Product cheapest=null;

         return suppliers.stream()
             .flatMap( supplier -> supplier.findProducts(query) )
             .sorted( (a,b) -> a.price.compareTo(b.price) )
             .first();
     }

     public boolean buy(String supplier, String productId)  {        
         return suppliers.stream()
             .filter( supplier -> 
                  supplier.getSupplierId().equals(supplier) )
             .map( supplier -> supplier.buy( productId ) )
             .findFirst();
     }
 }
```

So how would you implement a SupplierPlugin?

```
@Component
public class TestSupplier implements SupplierPlugin {

     @Reference
     DTOs dtos;

     static Product[] products = {

     };

     @Activate
     void activate() {
         InputStream in = TestSupplier.class
             .getResourceAsInputStream("products.json");
         products = dtos.decoder(Product[].class).get( 
     }

     public Set<Product> findProducts( String query ) {
        return Streams.of(products)
            .filter( product -> product.description.contains(query) )
            .collect( Collectors.toSet() );
     }
}
```

So the crucial difference between your terminology and the actual way to write plugins in OSGi is really the simple fact that Bundles are more or less *invisible*. The design is 100% around the services.

I've taken this question and created a little application to demonstrate the concepts. You can find it on the [OSGi enRoute Examples repository](https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute.examples/tree/master/osgi.enroute.examples.plugin.application)